# SharePoint Field Validation less than or equal to 7

Tags: validation-list-items

I need to validate a Text field and ensure the number enter is anything between 0 and 7. I tried many options but can't get it. What syntax do i add to this to allow any number from 0 thru 7 to be entered? So far i have

```
=LEN([Scheduled Day]+1)
+ISNUMBER([Scheduled Day]+0)
=2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=AND(VALUE([Scheduled Day])>=0,VALUE([Scheduled Day])<=7)
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. Unfortunately, it would not accept any number after adding this.

Comment: Try my new edit, that should cast the text to a number. It failed because it was a text field.

Comment: Thanks again Mike but it's not working. It's failing adding a number

Comment: one more edit. try again.

Comment: Mike, That did it.. Your awesome.. I really appreciate your attention and assistance with this... Have a great day, Rob

Comment: You're welcome! If the answer is what you were looking for, you can hit the checkmark to the left to accept it as an answer. That way, it will help anyone that has the same question on what did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add the field of "Number" type field and make the following settings.

- Field Type - Number
- Column settings: You can specify a minimum and maximum allowed value (Minimum -0 and Maximum-7)

[image]

It will do the out of box validation and throughs error if the number is not in the range.

Comment: Venkat, thank you. That was my original thought and very easy but i can't change the field to a number. It needs to stay as a text field for reason that it was designed as a text field and another process looks at that value.